# Clicking on navigation drawer item triggers the fragment behind on Huawei devices

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Click the navigation drawer items triggers the onClick event of the fragment behind it. It works well with other devices but one of my users complaints that he can't click navigation drawer item. He is using Huawei G Play Mini. Is there any way to solve this?

Here's my xml.

```
<!-- The important thing to note here is the added fitSystemWindows -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Your normal content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="#802196F3" />

        <!--<TextView
            android:id="@+id/acc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onMenuClicked"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_acc"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="16sp" />-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/setup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onMenuClicked"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_setup"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onMenuClicked"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_settings"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tutorial"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onMenuClicked"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_tutorial"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/converter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onMenuClicked"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_converter"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/about"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onMenuClicked"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_about"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buypro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onMenuClicked"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_buy"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: May I ask why don't you use [NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) instead of the LinearLayout?

Comment: i didn't know there's such class. Thanks for you info.

Comment: You have to show the code for the onClick event and the code for Fragment processing. The layout is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) instead of the LinearLayout.

You can see a more detailed sample [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

The sample shown on that page is this (I also added your FrameLayout):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- your content layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Mind the `app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"` which can be used to define a header layout (e.g your `drawer_header.xml` contains a single ImageView). To populate the list, you need a menu resource file (e.g. `drawer.xml` in the *menu* dir, the `app:menu="@menu/drawer"` attribute links to that).